# How to use Streambuilder for managing two different types of user

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies, firebase-security

my application have two types of users one is Service provider & Service Seekers I have to manage  state of Two different types of user using steam builder in flutter

my application have two types of users one is Service provider & Service Seekers I have to manage  state of Two different types of user using stream-builder in flutter. I create a code where I can manage only one state of user I not able to manage second type of user please help!

[photo of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eXv7.png)